# How to use signal.signal?

Tags: python, signals

If I write a script like this

```
import signal
import os

def receive_signal(signum, frame):
    print('I am here!')

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, receive_signal)

print('pid:', os.getpid())

while True:
    pass
```

Then run this script. Such that it print

```
pid: 44552
```

Then I open a python shell and input these code:

```
>>> import os, signal
>>> os.kill(44552, signal.SIGTERM)
```

The expected result is the script program will print "I am here!". But the actual result is the program just quit. What's the problem?

Comment: It works for me as expected.  Can you give us more information?  If the script "just quits," what is its exit status as reported by the shell?  What python version?  What OS?

Comment: @pilcrow python version 3.7.4, os windows 10, errorlevel is 15